# Nested field form validation within MVC .Net unobtrusive validation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

This code validates properly:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
</div>
```

This code doesn't validate properly:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 required" })
<div class="col-md-8">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control required" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.FirstName)
</div>
```

model.User from the second chunk of code is the same type of object as "m" in the first chunk of code.

Here's a chunk from the model showing the custom validator attribute.

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
[Required()]
[FirstLastName]
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```

Here's the FirstLastName attribute, which works properly for the first chunk of code but NOT the second.

```
public class FirstLastNameAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public FirstLastNameAttribute() :
        base(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_\!\#\^\~ ]{1,31}(?<!\.)$")
    {
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstLastNameErrorMessage";
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages);
    }
}
```

HTML output of first chunk of code that does work properly

```
<input class="input-validation-error text-box single-line form-control" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Allowed characters: a-Z, 0-9, .-_!#^~, and space.  Cannot end with a period.  Must be 1-32 characters." data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_\!\#\^\~ ]{1,31}(?<!\.)$" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="asdf." aria-required="true">
```

HTML output of second chunk of code that does NOT work properly

```
<input type="text" value="" name="User.FirstName" id="User_FirstName" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_\!\#\^\~ ]{1,31}(?&lt;!\.)$" data-val-regex="Allowed characters: a-Z, 0-9, .-_!#^~, and space.  Cannot end with a period.  Must be 1-32 characters." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line form-control" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: right center; cursor: auto;" aria-required="true">
```

Is there something wrong with nested object validation?  Is there a simple work around?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have shown - the `[Required]` attribute will work fine. But you have not indicated what `[FirstLastName]` is or does.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added the code for the FirstLastNameAttribute.  It works properly for the first bit of code, but not for the second.  Required attribute works properly for BOTH sets of code.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Show the html output for both cases.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added the output to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Neither will work for `[FirstLastName]` because neither is generating the necessary `data-val-regex=".."` and `data-val-regex-pattern=".."` attributes. I assume because you have not registered the attribute in `Global.asax`

Comment: The first one does work, although maybe improperly.  You were correct, I was missing "            DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
                typeof(FirstLastNameAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));".  I've now added it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91534/discussion-between-camhart-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Based on your html, the first one could never have worked (not the client side validation anyway) despite your claim.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/v7CiNMm.png
The error doesn't show up until AFTER I click the submit button.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference.  But it does appear to do validation--although maybe not client side.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why it wasn't working.

For some reason (and I don't understand why, so if anyone can explain please do so and I'll change the accepted answer) having the parenthesis "()" after the Required attribute broke it.  Once I removed the parenthesis, everything worked.

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
[Required]
[FirstLastName]
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```

It also didn't work because of the regex expression I was using.  It didn't like the reverse lookup `(?<!\.)` portion.  So upon removing that, it worked.